# Splitting program changes memory?

Tags: c++

I want to split up all classes from my program into cpp and hpp files, each file containing few classes from the same topic. Like this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class TopicFoo_Class1 {
    ... (Functions, variables, public/privates, etc.)
}
class TopicFoo_Class2 {
    ... (Functions, variables, public/privates, etc.)
}
class TopicBar_Class1 {
    ... (Stuff)
}
class TopicBar_Class2 {
    ... (Stuff)
}
int main(int argc, const char** argv) { ... }
```

into:

foo.hpp:

```
class TopicFoo_Class1 {
    ... (Declarations)
}
class TopicFoo_Class2 {
    ... (Declarations)
}

foo.cpp:
#include <cstdio>
#include "foo.hpp"
void TopicFoo_Class1::function1 { ... }
void TopicFoo_Class2::function1 { ... }

bar.hpp:
class TopicBar_Class1 {
    ... (Declarations)
}
class TopicBar_Class2 {
    ... (Declarations)
}
```

bar.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "bar.hpp"
void TopicBar_Class1::function1 { ... }
void TopicBar_Class2::function1 { ... }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"
int main(int argc, const char** argv) { ... }
```

The plan is to compile `foo.o` and `bar.o`, then compile `main.cpp` along with the object files to form `foo_bar_executable`, instead of just compiling a big `main.cpp` into `foo_bar_executable`.

This is just an example, header guards and better names will be included.

1. I'm wondering, will this affect program speed? Some `cpp`s will depend on other topics' `hpp`s to compile, and multiple `cpp`s will depend on one `hpp`.
2. Could the multiple includes of the same file by different `cpp` files cause lag?
3. Is there a better way to split up my code?
4. Which one is faster?
5. Is it possible to run `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o foo_bar_executable`?
6. How would the above command work?
7. Should I make `foo.hpp` contain most required includes and include it in most files? This might make it faster(?)

Comment: One question per question, please. Not _seven_.

Comment: I highly recommend one class per file set.  Place the class declaration (the `class` statement) in the header file (e.g. foo.hpp), and the implementation in another file (e.g. foo.cpp).  A nice benefit of this process is that once the source is compiled, it doesn't need to be compiled again (unless changed), which speeds up your build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I'm wondering, will this affect program speed? Some cpps will depend on other topics' hpps to compile, and multiple cpps will depend on one hpp.

You are mixing things that affect the build speed with run-time speed of your executable. The run-time speed shouldn't change. For a small project the difference in build time may be negligible. For larger projects, initial build times may be long, but subsequent ones may become much shorter. The reason is that you only need to rebuild what changed, and re-link.

> 2. Could the multiple includes of the same file by different cpp files cause lag?

Including a file always adds some delta to the build time. But it's something you'd need to measure. Nowadays compilers are pretty good with doing that in a smart fashion. If you couple that with smart header specification (no superfluous includes in headers, forward declarations and such), and precompiled headers, you shouldn't see a significant slowdown.

> 3. Is there a better way to split up my code?

Depends on the code. It's highly subjective.

> 4. Which one is faster?

Measure for yourself, we can't predict it for you.

> 5. Is it possible to run g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o foo_bar_executable?

Last I checked the GCC docs, it was.

> 6. How would the above command work?

It will take the above source files and produce a single executable

> 7. Should I make foo.hpp contain most required includes and include it in most files? This might make it faster(?)

I wouldn't recommend that. Include the bare minimum to make the single line program `#include "foo.hpp"` compile successfully. Headers should strive to be minimal and complete (kind of like a certain quality of posts on SO).

Answer (score 1):

> m wondering, will this affect program speed?

No.

> Could the multiple includes of the same file by different cpp files cause lag?

No.

> Which one is faster?

Speed is not really important to most programs, and how you arrange your files has no effect on run-time performance.

> Is it possible to run g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o foo_bar_executable

Yes

> How would the above command work?

RTFM

> Hey, I'm thirteen and a half!

We don't care.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer to question 1 is wrong: It will definitely have impacts on the speed, as it moves function implementations out of the view of the optimizer, so the resulting code will likely be less heavily optimized than the unsplit code. Of course, this difference is negligible in most cases, but it exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it will not affect speed except if you're relying on heavy optimizations, but as a self described "newbie", you likely won't be worrying about this yet. Often in the trade-off between maintaining a code structure to improve optimization vs. improving maintainability, maintenance will usually be the higher priority.
2. It might make compilation longer, but won't affect the executable. With a proper makefile, you might see compilation actually improve.
3. It's all subjective. Some packages split up the source *per function*.
4. No affect on executable.
5. Yes, but would recommend learning about makefiles, then you're compiling only what needs to be compiled.
6. It will compile the files, link to some default libraries, and output the executable. If you're interested in what is happening behind the scenes, compile with verbosity turned on. You can also compile to assembler, which can be really interesting to look at.
7. Ideally, each source file should include only the headers it needs.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I'm wondering, will this affect program speed?

It can, but it might not.

When functions are not defined in a single translation unit, the compiler can not optimize the function calls using inline expansion. However, if enabled, some linkers can perform inlining across translation units.

On the other hand, your program might not benefit from inlining optimization.

> Some cpps will depend on other topics' hpps to compile, and multiple cpps will depend on one hpp.

This is irrelevant to the speed of the compiled program.

> 2. Could the multiple includes of the same file by different cpp files cause lag?

It may have a (possibly insignificant) effect on compilation time from scratch.

> 3. Is there a better way to split up my code?

This is subjective. The more you split your code, the less you need to recompile when you make changes. The less you split, the faster it is to compile the entire project from scratch.

> 4. Which one is faster?

Possibly neither.

> 5. Is it possible to run g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o foo_bar_executable?

Yes.

> 6. How would the above command work?

Use the `man g++` command.

> 7. Should I make foo.hpp contain most required includes and include it in most files? This might make it faster(?)

No. Including unneeded files slows compilation. Besides this severely reduces the biggest advantage of splitting translation units, which is the lack of needing to compile the entire project when small part changes.